# Loop through subview to check for empty UITextField - Swift

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift, fast-enumeration

I"m wondering how to essentially transform the objective c code below into swift.

This will loop through all the subviews on my desired view, check if they are textfields, and then check if they are empty of not.

```
for (UIView *view in contentVw.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"%@", view);
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textfield = (UITextField *)view;
        if (([textfield.text isEqualToString:""])) {
            //show error
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where i am with swift translation so far:

```
for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if view.isKindOfClass(UITextField) {
        //...

    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift 5 and Swift 4: -
A Very simple answer you can understand easyly : - You can handle all kind of Objects like UILable, UITextfields, UIButtons, UIView, UIImages . any kind of objecs etc.

```
for subview in self.view.subviews
{
    if subview is UITextField
    {
        //MARK: - if the sub view is UITextField you can handle here
        if subview.text == ""
        {
            //MARK:- Handle your code
        }
    }
    if subview is UIImageView
    {
     //MARK: - check image
      if subview.image == nil
      {
             //Show or use your code here
      }

    }
}

//MARK:- You can use it any where, where you need it
//Suppose i need it in didload function we can use it and work it what do you need

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for subview in self.view.subviews
    {
        if subview is UITextField
        {
         //MARK: - if the sub view is UITextField you can handle here
            if subview.text == ""
            {
               //MARK:- Handle your code
            }
        }
        if subview is UIImageView
        {
          //MARK: - check image
            if subview.image == nil
                {
                 //Show or use your code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 80):

**Update for Swift 2 (and later):** As of Swift 2/Xcode 7 this can be simplified.

- Due to the Objective-C "lightweight generics", `self.view.subviews`
  is already declared as `[UIView]` in Swift, therefore the cast
  is not necessary anymore.
- Enumeration and optional cast can be combined with to a for-loop
  with a case-pattern.

This gives:

```
for case let textField as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
    if textField.text == "" {
        // show error
        return
    }
}
```

---

Old answer for **Swift 1.2:**

In Swift this is nicely done with the *optional downcast* operator `as?`:

```
for view in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        if textField.text == "" {
            // show error
            return
        }
    }
}
```

See ["Downcasting"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_490)
in the Swift book.