# Type casting in for-in loop

Tags: for-loop, swift, for-in-loop

I have this for-in loop:

```
for button in view.subviews {
}
```

Now I want button to be cast into a custom class so I can use its properties.

I tried this: `for button in view.subviews as AClass`

But it doesnt work and gives me an error:`'AClass' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'`

And I tried this: `for button:AClass in view.subviews`

But neither does that work.

Comment: How about `for button in view.subviews as [AClass]`

Comment: haha I didnt think of that, of course its better to cast the array into an array of AClass, thanks man. You can make an answer about it so I can give you some rep :)

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097958/loop-through-subview-to-check-for-empty-uitextfield-swift/25098005#25098005.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

For **Swift 2** and later:

Swift 2 adds *case patterns* to *for* loops, which makes it even easier and safer to type cast in a *for* loop:

```
for case let button as AClass in view.subviews {
    // do something with button
}
```

Why is this better than what you could do in **Swift 1.2** and earlier?  Because *case patterns* allow you to pick your specific type out of the collection.  It only matches the type you are looking for, so if your array contains a mixture, you can operate on only a specific type.

For example:

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 1.2, "Hello", true, [1, 2, 3], "World!"]
for case let str as String in array {
    print(str)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Hello
> World!
> ```

---

For **Swift 1.2**:

In this case, you are casting `view.subviews` and not `button`, so you need to downcast it to the array of the type you want:

```
for button in view.subviews as! [AClass] {
    // do something with button
}
```

Note:  If the underlying array type is not `[AClass]`, this will crash.  That is what the `!` on `as!` is telling you.  If you're not sure about the type you can use a conditional cast `as?` along with optional binding `if let`:

```
if let subviews = view.subviews as? [AClass] {
    // If we get here, then subviews is of type [AClass]
    for button in subviews {
        // do something with button
    }
}
```

For **Swift 1.1** and earlier:

```
for button in view.subviews as [AClass] {
    // do something with button
}
```

Note:  This also will crash if the subviews aren't all of type `AClass`.  The safe method listed above also works with earlier versions of Swift.

Comment: Just a note for others like me who didn't get it at first - the class name has to go inside ```[ ]``` brackets exactly like in this example. Maybe it's just me but I thought it was just a formatting choice in the code sample at first :) I presume this is because we are casting to an array.

Comment: @kmcgrady Its just `[Class]` looks much better than `Array<Class>`.

Comment: So out of curiosity, is there a way to do multiple case statements inside the for loop?  E. G. if I want to do one thing to buttons, another to text fields?

Answer (score 133):

This option is more secure:

```
for case let button as AClass in view.subviews {
}
```

or swifty way:

```
view.subviews
  .compactMap { $0 as AClass }
  .forEach { .... }
```

Answer (score 6):

The answers provided are correct, I just wanted to add this as an addition.

When using a for loop with force casting, the code will crash (as already mentioned by others).

```swift
for button in view.subviews as! [AClass] {
    // do something with button
}
```

But instead of using an if-clause,

```swift
if let subviews = view.subviews as? [AClass] {
    // If we get here, then subviews is of type [AClass]
    ...
}
```

another way is to use a while-loop:

```swift
/* If you need the index: */
var iterator = view.subviews.enumerated().makeIterator()
while let (index, subview) = iterator.next() as? (Int, AClass) {
    // Use the subview
    // ...
}

/* If you don't need the index: */
var iterator = view.subviews.enumerated().makeIterator()
while let subview = iterator.next().element as? AClass {
    // Use the subview
    // ...
}
```

Which seems to be more convenient if some elements (but not all) of the array might be of type `AClass`.

Although for now (as of Swift 5), I'd go for the for-case loop:

```swift
for case let (index, subview as AClass) in view.subviews.enumerated() {
    // ...
}

for case let subview as AClass in view.subviews {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just one doubt here...does the swift enumerated function performs iterations/loop here.. just thinking refactoring for losing performance will not be great...thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a `where` clause

```
for button in view.subviews where button is UIButton {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The where clause is a boolean guard, but does not cast the type of `button` inside the loop body, which is the goal of the other solutions.  So this will only run the loop body on elements of `view.subviews` which are `UIButton`s, but doesn't help e.g. in calling `AClass`-specific methods on `button`.

Comment: @JohnWhitley you are correct that `where` only guards and does not cast.

Comment: `where` may be more elegant and readable for cases (pun unintentional) where you need only a boolean guard.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform the casting and be safe at the same time with this:

```
for button in view.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? AClass }) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have an **index** in your loop:

```
for case let (index, button as AClass) in view.subviews.enumerated() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by vacawama was correct in Swift 1.0. And no longer works with Swift 2.0.

If you try, you will get an error similar to:

> '[AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[AClass]';

In Swift 2.0 you need to write like:

```
for button in view.subviews as! [AClass]
{
}
```