# How to iterate over array of Any

Tags: swift, iteration

I want to know how I would iterate over an array of objects of different types. The array looks like this:

```
var messages: [Any] = [SentMessage(sent_text: "Halla", date_sent: "24.des", isSent: true, sending: false), RecievedMessage(profile_image: UIImage(named: "baseline_account_box_black_18pt")!, recieved_text: "Hei hva skjer?", date_recieved: "25.des", isRecieved: true)]
```

I tried to convert iterator like this:

```
for i in messages{

    guard let received = ReceivedMessage(i) else{
        return
    }


}
```

**ReceivedMessages** and **SentMessages** are both structs, if it is necessary to see more code, just ask.

Comment: "I want to know how I would iterate over an array of objects of different types" Best way: don't.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26076910/1630618

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use optional binding :

```
guard let received = i as? ReceivedMessage
```

Instead of declaring `messages` as `[Any]`, make `ReceivedMessage` and `SentMessage` adopt a common protocol and then `messages` would be an array of objects adopting that protocol:

```
protocol Message {

}

struct SentMessage: Message {

}

struct ReceivedMessage: Message {

}

var messages: [Message]
```

Comment: I understand that, but if I am adopting everything from a protocol, I could just create one struct as well?

Comment: @EliasKnudsen Of course, preferably, with a boolean to differentiate between received and sent messages

Comment: Thanks, it was dumb to create to different structs, a message share many similar properites, only difference is whether it was sent or received.

Comment: Maybe introduce an enum for the status of the message? You'll probably discover over time that a message can probably be in more states than just sent and received

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Be