# For-in loop and type casting only for objects which match type

Tags: swift, casting, for-in-loop

I have seen answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076772/type-casting-in-for-in-loop) which explain how to tell the compiler that an array is of a certain type in a loop.

However, does Swift give a way so that the loop only loops over items of the specified type in the array rather than crashing or not executing the loop at all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a for-loop with a case-pattern:

```
for case let item as YourType in array {
    // `item` has the type `YourType` here 
    // ...
}
```

This will execute the loop body only for those items in the
array which are of the type (or can be cast to) `YourType`.

Example (from
[Loop through subview to check for empty UITextField - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097958/loop-through-subview-to-check-for-empty-uitextfield-swift/25098005#25098005)):

```
for case let textField as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
    if textField.text == "" {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for something simple like that :)

Comment: Oh - and also, does it loops over an item if it is a subclass of your specified class?

Comment: @QuestionAsker: Yes, because an instance of a subclass can always be cast to an instance of the superclass. – Just try it!

Comment: Thank you! Last thing: I changed it to a dictionary, so should I now use: `for case (let key as String, let item as YourType) in dictionary {...}`? It seems to work, but I want to check if this will function as I intend

Answer (score 0):

Given an array like this

```
let things: [Any] = [1, "Hello", true, "World", 4, false]
```

you can also use a combination of `flatMap` and `forEach` fo iterate through the `Int` values

```
things
    .flatMap { $0 as? Int }
    .forEach { num in
        print(num)
}
```

or

```
for num in things.flatMap({ $0 as? Int }) {
    print(num)
}
```

In both cases you get the following output

```
// 1
// 4
```

Comment: flatMap is deprecated, use compactMap instead (Swift 4)