# For Each loop and type casting only for objects which match type

Tags: vb.net, collections, foreach, casting

Is there a special syntax which will loop over only elements of a certain type in a collection?

For example:

```
For Each number As Integer In {0, "string", 4.6, 7, someClassInstance}
Next
```

I want a similar syntax to the above which will only loop through the 1st and 4th element in the array.

However, according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx):

> "The data type of element must be such that the data type of the elements of group can be converted to it."

so I cannot use the above syntax to do such a thing.

---

The actual example I'm dealing with in my code is:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass
End Class

Public Class SubClass1 : Inherits BaseClass 
    Public x As Integer
End Class

Public Class SubClass2 : Inherits BaseClass
End Class
```

Main Code:

```
Dim someList As List(Of BaseClass)

For Each instance In someList
    'Do something with instance.x
Next
```

So I would need to check if `instance` is of type `SubClass1` and cast every time I used `x`.

---

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813225/swift-for-in-loop-and-type-casting-only-for-objects-which-match-type) a while ago for Swift. I'm hoping for a similar answer in VB.

Comment: But what would that group represent?  Typically you do `For Each` on a homogeneous set.  That data would have to be stored `As Object`

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that is an array of Objects. Perhaps a better example is in my code I have a collection of a `MustInherit` Class, and only want to loop through objects of a specific class.

Comment: I don't know in VB but in C# it is "is".  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No there is no "special syntax" for that as heterogeneous collection aren't often the *way to go* in .Net

Though, you can use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) to "filter" that collection according to some type :

```
For Each number In {0, "string", 4.6, 7, someClassInstance}.OfType(Of Integer)
```

*Note : that code can compile only if Option Strict is set to Off as Option Strict On forbids implicit Object type*

Regarding the edit, it's often a code smell to have to check derived type when you have a collection of base ; meaning there should be an mustoverride/overridable method in the class hierarchy to handle that.

Comment: Thanks - using a filter is a good idea for me. What do you mean by the mustoverride method?

Comment: @QuestionAsker I mean doing real Object Oriented code, when you create a collection of base, you explicitely stating that what you want is a collection of some object belonging to that hierarchy and don't care which one you have because you're only intrested in what they share commonly. And then you want to know which one you have, in total contradiction with the previous sentence.

Comment: ...  In contrary if the base class had a method overrided (if needed) by it's inheritors you really don't care which one is in the collection because calling that method will "go to the right one" without you even knowing. tl;dr **polymorphism**